# Printed Output Dependent on Window Size

Tags: javascript, css, printing-web-page

As the title suggests, I'm working on a project and need to have print capability on a specific page. This page is 90% text. Changing the window size affects the size of the content printed on each page. This is odd because I'm already using an `@print` media query in my stylesheet.

In other words, when inspecting the print dialog while the window is at full width, the preview shows small print and all the content is stretched out across the page. When halving the screen size and again inspecting the print dialog, the content and text become bigger and better fit the page. This behavior persists even when I change the unit of measurement for `font-size` from `px` to `pt`.

Put simply, the size of the printed output is responsive to the size of the window. Is this normal / to be expected? Is there a way around this? I don't see this behavior on other sites. I would think that whether you attempt to print at full window size of half window size, the size of the printed content should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Either use a printing stylsheet [as explained by mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Printing)

```
<link href="/path/to/print.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" />
```

or use a print [media query css selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) in your regular stylesheet.

```
@media print { 
 /* set a constant font size, width and height, hide toolbars etc */
}
```

Comment: Ah I should have clarified, updated my original post, I'm already using a print media query in my stylesheet and putting all print related styles in there.

Comment: in that case use `display: none !important;` for all things you don't want to see and set a fixed `width: 160mm;` or similar on the relevant textblock?

Comment: Maybe I should have lead with the crux to your question: which browser are you using?

Comment: Using the latest version of Chrome. The fixed width suggestion did work, so thanks! Still, not sure why it was resizing in the first place, so would appreciate any thoughts

Comment: My chromium version 70 looks like it is resizing the text, however it is just rescaling the page to fit in the window. Could that be what you're experiencing?

Comment: Nah I've seen that behavior, this is a little different. This is more like window is at 1100px wide, open print dialog and see two paragraphs on first page. Now close print dialog, cut window width in half to 550px, open print dialogue, now the first paragraph takes up the first page and the second paragraph has moved to the second page.